# R conditional operations (transfer of data) - working on a subset of data only - avoiding loops

Tags: r

While cleaning huge lots of data, I fell on the following problem :

I have a dataframe with clean columns and unclean columns I want to clean by replacing the data (I have to keep both columns).

```
data1 <- c("a01", "a2", "a03", "a1", "a08")
data2 <- c("a01", "a02", "a03", "a01", "a08")
df <- data.frame(data1, data2)
```

I made a test that gives TRUE FALSE values in a test result column

```
df$dataClean <- grepl("^[a-z][0-9]$", df$data1)
```

Now I want to have an operation performed only on the part where the condition = TRUE. Basically I want to replace some values with others... But I would like to have some agile solution I can adapt to several usecases.

My first try doesn't work but it's the philosophy I would like to follow : working without loops...

```
df$data1 <- df$data2[df$dataClean]
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "data1", value = c(2L, 1L)) : replacement has 2 rows, data has 5
```

In excel, I was used to array formulas for these tasks... I'm looking a bit for the equivalent in R I guess :)

EDIT: 
Actually I found this one, but is it a loop isn't it ? :

```
df$data1 <- ifelse(df$dataClean, as.character(df$data2), as.character(df$data1))
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `df$data1 <- with(df, ifelse(dataClean, data2, data1))`, not sure though. `ifelse` is a vectorized function and hence doesn't use a loop as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative to your `ifelse` approach, but it depends on "data1" and "data2" being character columns, not `factor`s.

```
## Your data -- but with stringsAsFactors = FALSE
data1 <- c("a01", "a2", "a03", "a1", "a08")
data2 <- c("a01", "a02", "a03", "a01", "a08")
df <- data.frame(data1, data2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#   data1 data2
# 1   a01   a01
# 2    a2   a02
# 3   a03   a03
# 4    a1   a01
# 5   a08   a08

df$dataClean <- grepl("^[a-z][0-9]$", df$data1)

## Just basic extraction and substitution
df$data1[df$dataClean] <- df$data2[df$dataClean]
df
#   data1 data2 dataClean
# 1   a01   a01     FALSE
# 2   a02   a02      TRUE
# 3   a03   a03     FALSE
# 4   a01   a01      TRUE
# 5   a08   a08     FALSE
```